# Suggestions on creating & deploying minimized JavaScript with NAnt?

Tags: javascript, nant, packing, minimized

Do you have any suggestions or examples on how to deploy minimized (min) versions of JavaScript files using NAnt?

Are there any good command line applications, or scripts to assist with minimizing or packing JavaScript on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with taking a dependency on Java, you can use [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) (otherwise there's the [.NET port of it](http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor)).

Comment: Interesting. Since it has a command line interface, I can probably hook it up into Aptana somehow as a tool. Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

Kariem (my colleague) wrote an Open Source nAnt task wrapper around JSMin (Douglas Crockford's C# code) which can be found [here](http://ra-ajax.org/custom-nant-jsmin-task-for-minifying-javascript-files.blog)...

And when you later figure you want to also do a GZip task in nAnt, feel free to also use our (also Open Source) [nAnt gzipper](http://ra-ajax.org/webresource-axd-and-javascript-gzip-compression-a-simple-solution.blog)

Both of these are a part of the download of [Ra-Ajax](http://ra-ajax.org) which can be found at the [Ra-Ajax download page at google code](http://code.google.com/p/ra-ajax/)

Ohh yeah, almost forgot to mention that they both have a permissive Open Source license (free of charge to use) though in the "spirit of Douglas" we choose to release them both under his own custom Open Source license which roughly is an MIT license though with a "use not for evil purposes" clause ;)

We found that "no evil" clause so funny we had to use it ourselves. Beside we're building on Doug's code so it would only be fair to build in "his spirit" too, right...? ;)

Have fun :)